# AWS RDS PostgreSQL Storage

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, postgresql-9.6

One of my AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance is consuming too much storage even though there is no activity going on the Database. I have logical_replication switched ON, to use AWS DMS to replicate DBs to S3 bucket.

The transaction logs are getting generated which are taking the storage space, but as I said there are no activities going on the DB. That's confusing, can someone please help me understand this? The transaction logs gets cleaned up when I run a dummy update script on the DB. Is there any parameters which I can update to continuously cleaning the transaction log files?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. If there is data change. The transaction logs can be cleaned fine. But when there is no data change. The transaction logs keep going!